# HTML/JS: Remember <input> directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, node-webkit

I'm using this:

```
<input id="fileInput" class="upload-list" type="file" webkitdirectory directory />
```

to open a folder, and load all the files inside the folder.

I have a `.change()` trigger to capture the `onchange` and list all the files.
Every time I re-open the page, I have to manually select the folder.

Is there a way of saving the folder and opening the directory on start up?

I'm using Node Webkit (Chromium Based), so you can add some start-up lines if needed.

Comment: It seems you can get the relative path of the uploaded files, but not still not the absolute path for security reasons, so firstly you can't get the correct path, and secondly, `webkitdirectory` doesn't seem to accept a path as a value, it's a boolean attribute only as far as I can tell ?

Comment: Should I use nwdirectory instead? https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs : "nwdirectory is a bit similar to webkitdirectory because it let user select a directory too, but it will not enumerate all files under the directory but directly returns the path of directory, developers may want to use nwdirectory to get the path of a directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `nwdirectory` attribute instead of `webkitdirectory`. As the [wiki page](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/File-dialogs#select-directory-node-webkit) describes:

> **nwdirectory** is a bit similar to **webkitdirectory** because it let user
>   select a directory too, but it will not enumerate all files under the
>   directory but directly returns the path of directory, developers may
>   want to use `nwdirectory` to get the path of a directory.

So the following change fixed my problem:

```
<input id="fileInput" class="upload-list" type="file" nwdirectory directory />
```